# Retrieve table with jQuery and change color of all th's

Tags: jquery

I have on the page alot of tables, but with a jQuery I need to get only that `table` which has 1 `th` with the class `ms-vh2-nograd`, all others I pass.

So in other words I search for `th.ms-vh2-nograd` and I need to get parent parent I think
and then for each `th` in that `table` I need to set background color to white.

Here is the code which I have, but it doesnt work, anyone has any idea?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $table=$("table.ms-listview ms-vh2-nograd")
    $table.("th").each(function()
    {
        this.style.backgroundcolor="white"
    });
});
```

UPDATE:
And the links in those th's must not have hover over ... functionality

Comment: what's the html structure of the tables provide the html code

Comment: *"UPDATE: And the links in those th's must not have hover over ... functionality"*. And how are we supposed to know that? How is the hover functionality being added. You're adding more requirements to your question but with no more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.style.backgroundcolor="white"
```

should be:

```
$(this).css('background-color','white')
```

Comment: This is just a small part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$table.find("th").each(function()
{
    ...
```

instead.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `.children()` only goes down one level of the DOM. This may work depending on the HTML structure of the table, but if they use `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` or `<tbody>` tags inside the `<table>` then it won't find the selected elements.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I have on the page alot of tables, ... I need to get only that `table` which has 1 `th` with the class `ms-vh2-nograd`"
>
> ...
>
> "I search for `th.ms-vh2-nograd` and I need to get parent parent I think and then for each `th` in that `table` I need to set background color to white"*

When you say *"`table` which has 1 `th` with the class `ms-vh2-nograd`"*, I assume you mean at least one, or that there will never be more than one.

If the `th` elements are all within the same row, you could do this

```
$("table.ms-listview th.ms-vh2-nograd").siblings()
                                       .andSelf()
                                       .css('backgroundColor',"white");
```

This gets the `th.ms-vh2-nograd`, then grabs its siblings, and finally adds the original selection back in using `andSelf()`.

Then it uses `.css()` to set the style.

---

If the there are `th` elements in other rows, then use `.closeset('table').find('th')` to get them...

```
$("table.ms-listview th.ms-vh2-nograd").closest('table')
                                       .find('th')
                                       .css('backgroundColor',"white");
```

Comment: really good one, but if that th has image ... and i set the background to white, will it overwrite the image or ... how do i say no image?

Comment: @user1002583: Instead of `backgroundColor` just use `background`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-vh2-nograd th").each(function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundcolor','white');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $table=$("table.ms-listview ms-vh2-nograd")
    $table.("th").each(function()
    {
        this.style.backgroundcolor="white"
    });
});
```

There are a number of problems with this. For a start, you're not using the `var` keyword when declaring your variable, so you're (probably) polluting the global scope with a variable that doesn't need to be there.

The selector `table.ms-listview ms-vh2-nograd` is trying to detect an element created with a tag `<ms-vh2-nograd>` (which obviously doesn't exist), since it's a class you need to use `` `table.ms-listview .ms-vh2-nograd `` - if you're only interested in `<th>` elements that have this class, you may want to use `table.ms-listview th.ms-vh2-nograd`. That selector, however, identifies a set of `<th>` elements - not the table that contains them (so the variable name is misleading).

There's a syntax error in the line after that - `$table.("th")` isn't valid - you'll need to call a jQuery function on `$table`.

Finally, there's no need to use an `.each()` to set the CSS property on all of the matched elements - calling `.css()` on the set will apply it to all of the elements contained within.

I'd revise the code to this:

```
$(function() {
    var $table = $('table.ms-listview .ms-vh2-nograd').closest('table');
    $($table).find('th').css('background-color','white');
});
```

That identifies the table containing the `<th>` element (not the `<th>` element itself) and stores it in the `$table` variable (which is scoped to the function, because it doesn't need to be global). Then it finds all `<th>` elements within that `<table>` element and applies the CSS property to all of them.

Answer (score -1):

I guess "ms-vh2-nograd" is a class, so try this:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $table=$("table.ms-listview .ms-vh2-nograd")
    $table.("th").each(function()
    {
        this.style.backgroundcolor="white"
    });
});
```